# Getting blank zip file when getting created

Tags: java

I am getting blank zip even though I am writing images to it .Can some one let me know what I am doing wrong?I am trying to add images to the zip file .Its creating a zip file but with blank entry on it .so why its not writing the file to it?

```
         int i = 0;
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Iterator iterator = datas.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        byte[] bs = (byte[]) iterator.next();

        BufferedImage image = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bs);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();

        // write the image to a file
        File outputfile = new File("image" + i + ".jpg");
        System.out.println("*************************" + outputfile.getAbsolutePath());
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
        i++;
        filenames.add(outputfile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    
    // Create the ZIP file

     //create object of FileOutputStream
     FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipName);
     
     //create object of ZipOutputStream from FileOutputStream
     ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    for (int k = 0; k < filenames.size(); k++) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filenames.get(k).toString());
        

        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        File file = new File(filenames.get(k).toString());
        String entryname = file.getName();
        zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryname));

        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            zout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        zout.closeEntry();
        
        fis.close();
        }
    
    zout.flush();
    fout.flush();
    zout.close();
    fout.close();
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you [edit] your question and change the code to a [mcve] please? That way people can easily give it a try and fix whatever is wrong. See also [ask].

Comment: If you add `System.out.println(datas.size());` and run, what does it print?

Comment: Are you supplying the correct images? That code looks like it should run . It will be easier for you to test if you separate the zip part say as `static void writeZip(File zipName, List<File> filenames) throws IOException` and then test zip separately to imageio.